# ACN/PCN Reporting System - Tire Pressure

Tags: takeoff, runways, icao-sarps

I have an Airbus A320neo **WV054** and I want to operate at a RWY that has PCN **55/R/D/Y/T**. Below is my aircraft ACN data as per the Aircraft Characteristics Manual.

[image]

Looking at the table I can see that my max ACN value (54) is below the PCN value (55) on a rigid pavement with a Subgrade Strength Category **D**, meaning I can operate with my Maximum Ramp Weight.

However, my Tire Pressure (1.44 MPa) is less than the Maximum Allowable Tire Pressure Category **Y** (1.25 MPa). Does this mean that I am Tire Pressure Limited and I am unable to operate at the given runway?

I've gone through the regulations and all they mention is to make sure that PCN does not exceed the ACN value, and nothing about the Tire Pressure limit. Thank you.

Comment: 1.44 is less than 1.25???

Comment: no, it is not less, but more...